# Wigner's $9$-$j$ symbol - four electrons orbital angular momentum coupling

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, group-theory, representation-theory, interactions

In constructing the total angular momentum operator, that is the sum of 4 independent angular momentum operators:

$$J=J_1+J_2+J_3+J_4 $$
one has the following set of commuting operators and eigenvectors in case of the **uncoupled** configuration:

$$ {\textbf{J}_1^2,J_{1z},\textbf{J}_2^2,J_{2z},\textbf{J}_3^2,J_{3z},\textbf{J}_4^2,J_{4z}},$$

$$|j_1m_1\rangle|j_2m_2\rangle|j_3m_3\rangle|j_4m_4\rangle.$$

Now in the **coupled** representation, if one couple pairwise there are different choices. Most commons I have seen in books are:

$$|(j_1j_2)J_{12}(j_3j_4)J_{34};J\rangle \ and\ |(j_1j_3)J_{13}(j_2j_4)J_{24};J\rangle $$

Now the Wigner 9j symbols are within a constant the coefficients that allow us to go from one basis to another, thus

$$\langle (j_1j_2)J_{12}(j_3j_4)J_{34};J|{(j_1j_3)J_{13}(j_2j_4)J_{24};J}\rangle \propto \Bigg\{ \begin{matrix}
j_1 & j_2 & J_{12}\\
j_3 & j_4 & J_{34}\\
J_{13} & J_{24} & J\\
\end{matrix}
\Bigg\}.$$

I am more interested in

> extend coupling to n angular momenta by successive coupling of an extra angular momentum to the former n - 1 system [1]

In this case we have [2,3]

$$\langle [(j_1j_2)J_{12},j_3]J_{123},j_4;J|{[(j_4j_2)J_{42},j_3]J_{423},j_1;J}\rangle \propto \Bigg\{ \begin{matrix}
j_2 & J_{12} & j_{1}\\
J_{42} & j_3 & J_{423}\\
j_{4} & J_{123} & J\\
\end{matrix}
\Bigg\}.$$

and **here** my question and my doubt:

Is it possible to relate the following coupling scheme through a Wigner symbol ?

1. $$\langle [(j_1j_2)J_{12},j_3]J_{123},j_4;J|{[(j_2j_3)J_{23},j_4]J_{234},j_1;J}\rangle $$
2. $$\langle [(j_1j_2)J_{12},j_3]J_{123},j_4;J|{[(j_1j_2)J_{12},j_4]J_{124},j_3;J}\rangle $$

If yes, how can I build the Wigner 9j symbol (i.e. the positions of the $j$)? Is there any symbolic calculator or table where I can look for? It will really help me since I would like to extend the same also to the Wigner 12j and so on.

> **References**
>
> [1] Professor Dr. Kris L. G. Heyde - The Nuclear Shell Model - Study Edition (1994). pp 26
>
> [2] Edmonds - Angular momentum in quantum mechanics-Princeton, N.J., Princeton University Press  (1957). pp 104
>
> [3] Albert Messiah - Quantum Mechanics. 2 - John Wiley and Sons, Inc. (1961). pp 1067
>
> [4] A. P. Yutsis - Mathematical Apparatus of the Theory of Angular Momentum.

Comment: I think that since this can be seen as a recoupling of three of the four angular momentum (where two terms are of the type $j$ and one of the type $J_{i,k}$), the wigner's coefficient between these two coupling schemes reduces to Wigner's 6-j symbol.

Comment: what do you mean by "relate the scheme"?  Are you asking if 1. and 2. can be expressed in terms of standard 9-j symbols or are you asking if one can define this overlap, compute from the get-go, and figure out if the resulting symbols as 9-j-like properties?

Comment: I'm asking if 1. and 2. (each one separately) can be expressed in terms of 9-j symbols. Looking to Yutsis' graphs I think 1. and 2.  can be expressed as 6-j symbols as they can be seen as recoupling of three angular momentum (I'll post a more detailed description). As you said you have some contrains in building the 9-j coefficient and at first glance it seems not possible with the coupling chosen.

Comment: Yeah I don' have Jutsis with me but it's an extremely good reference, and I would not be surprised if you could express your overlap as a sum of 6j's.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think your overlaps reduce to the usual 9j symbols through symmetry operations.

In your first coupling scheme, you are forced by the scheme on the left to have $j_1,j_2$ and $J_{12}$ on the same row,
and then $J_{12}, j_3$ and $J_{123}$ in the same column, and then $J_{123}, j_4$ and $J$ on the same row, i.e something like
\begin{align}
\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
j_1&j_2&J_{12}\\
&&j_3\\
J&j_4&J_{123}\\
\end{array}\right\} \tag{1}
\end{align}
But then for your scheme on the right you have $j_2,j_3\to J_{23}$ so $j_2,j_3$ and $J_{23}$ must be either on the same row or column.  However, you can see this is not possible since $j_3$ must already be in the same column as $J_{12}$ and $J_{123}$, and cannot be in the same row as $j_2$ by your left coupling.

The same logic applies to your second coupling scheme, where from the left you'd have again (1) but this time you need to fit $J_{12}$ on the same line or column as $j_4$ when it's already in a given full line or column.

There are calculators but I don't think they will be useful since I don't think what you want is equivalent to a $9j$.  You probably have to build a custom function using the same idea of writing the standard 9j as a sum of 6j's.  Moreover, in your second scheme,  you can probably reorganize
\begin{align}
[J_{12}j_4]J_{124}j_3 \to [J_{12}j_3]J_{123}j_4
\end{align}
using a $6j$ symbol and make mileage there but again you'd have to do this as a custom function.

Note that it should not come as a surprise to get a negative answer.  Historically the 9j was introduced to deal with the undoing of $jj$ coupling back to an LS coupling to compute matrix elements of - say - the spin-orbit coupling or some tensor operator acting on angular momenta only.  Hence by design it is not constructed for recursive coupling of the type you want.